# Compiling a Tomcat project and spinning a dev Tomcat up from the command line

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, command-line-interface

I have a web project in Eclipse with all the normal stuff: Some data access classes in `src`, some JSP pages in `WebContent` and some static files (css, images) in sub-directories in `WebContent`.

In Eclipse I can easily compile the project and spin up a dev Tomcat instance via Eclipse's *Servers* pane.

However I will need to move this project to a remote machine without GUI access. I have only terminal access which I will so to make minor changes to Java code and JSP files. After doing so, I need to compile the whole project and spin up a dev Tomcat to view the result.

Is there a command line tool which can compile a Tomcat project and spin up a dev Tomcat with the project?

On the [Tomcat site](https://tomcat.apache.org) I found the [Tomcat Client Deployer](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_using_the_Client_Deployer_Package) mentioned. However this tool looks quite complicated needing a lot of configuration. My (Eclipse) project  however contains all the config information already - I just would need a command line tool which reads them, compiles the WAR and spins up Tomcat...

**New Idea:**

Maybe Eclipse can be called from the command line without opening a GUI to do this?

Comment: [`ant`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_creating_war_files.htm) looks like a good option

Comment: Where .java files are? same directory as .class ones? if so may a manual compile would be the easiest way

Comment: @LMC Thanks for your comment. Eclipse puts the calss file for a file `dao.java` which sits in `src/com/package/my` into the directory `bin/com/package/my`.  So it would be great if the command line tool did the same.

Comment: I meant to ask where are *.java files on remote machine. They should be packed inside the war file.